# Why aren't there any more elections?

Tags: discussion

I just checked the elections. I saw that they are held on 2011 and 2012 and never again. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[How often are moderator elections held?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135749/192154) explains this. Short summary:

- they take place at any frequency, depending on demand
- mods are elected "for life-time" (as long as they volunteer – they of course can "exit" on their wish) or until they're "absent for six months"

So obviously, our mods still can cope, there's no demand, and nobody left ;)

Comment: How can be *demand* ? Can someone start a poll or something?

Comment: @SarpSTA SE staff keeps tabs on the workloads (as far as I'm aware) and if they think the moderators are getting overwhelmed they will arrange an election. They'll also typically hold elections if a mod contacts them and asks to step down or if the existing mod team requests additional help.